# What is the active voice of this sentence?

Tags: active-voice

Context:
"If I got locked away"
 
And we lost it all today.

What is the active voice of "If I got locked away"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If someone locked me away

Either way, it doesn't really scan,  since the first stanza has six syllables and the second seven. Unless you pronounce "locked" with two syllables ("lock-ed"), which is clumsy.

Anyway. Other examples of this structure:

> "Should it be stolen" -> "Should someone steal it"
>
> "It got damaged" -> "Someone damaged it"
>
> "When you got promoted" -> "When someone promoted you".

Comment: It seems important to point out that a sentence doesn't have voice, but that a clause does. For instance, what is the voice of the sentence  _"We lost it all today when I was locked away"_ ... ?